# How to use AutoTouch to get device infomation

Tags: autotouch

I want to get information about the current device.

I thought I would find some attribute of AutoTouch like this

```
const { getScreenInfo } = at;
console.log(1, at);
console.log(2, getScreenInfo());
```

but the result is not what I expected

```
10-13 08:21:38 1 {}
10-13 08:21:38 2 {"bitDepth":32,"width":414,"height":736,"scale":3}
```

Looking forward to your support